# Why the if is done 1time in a each loop

Tags: javascript, html, list

I'm trying to loop over each article in a list but in my JS the if statement is done 1x at the end. (look the scheme bellow)

1. loop over each article
2. take the article in the collection where the title is the same as
   the actual title
3. check the owner of the article in the collection and the user
4. if it's not the same hide the article

And it's only hiding the first article:

```
  $('.titreArticle').each(function(i, obj) {
    title= obj.textContent;
    var art =  Articles.findOne({titre: title });
    console.log("id co: " + id + " /id art: " + art.owner);
    //it only hide the first <li>
    if(art.owner != id){
      document.getElementById("liArticle").style.display = "none";
    }
  });
```

And I join 2 screenshots:
[image: We can see the check of the owner id]
[image: And we can see that he only hide the first one (but the first one shouldn't be hide)]

We can see the check of the owner id in the first picture. 
Then we can see that he only hide the first one (but the first one shouldn't be hide)

[EDIT] there is my template code for the Article:

```
<template name="article">
  <li id="liArticle">
    <div>
        <img id="pic" src= {{photo}} />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label class="titreArticle">{{titre}}</label>
        {{#if isOwner}}
           {{#unless wantModif}}
        <button class="delete" style="color:black">&times;</button>
        <button class="modify" style="color:black">modifier</button>
          {{/unless}}
        {{/if}}
        <p id="dateHeure"><strong>Ecrit par: {{username}} le {{date}} à {{heure}} {{lieux}} </strong></p>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div id="textContenu">
        <span>{{text}}</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</template>
```

Comment: Because IDs must be unique. `document.getElementById` will always return the first element that has the passed ID.

Comment: But they are unique, the actual user id is the first "id" then it's the owner id of each articles and you can own 100 articles if you've wrote 100 you see ? @Felix Kling

Comment: I see more than one element with ID `liArticle`. An ID can (should) only be assigned to a single element.

Comment: If you have six elements with the id `liArticle`, how would `document.getElementById("liArticle")` know which one it should select?

Comment: `But they are unique` - unique means that an ID appears only once in a given HTML document, not once per element

Comment: Oh you were speaking about that, okay but I can't do it in an other way because it's a template if you want I can post the code of the template

Comment: @Jerome - how about you fix the template not to use the same ID for the `<li>`

Comment: @JaromandaX but how could I fix that ? If I remove the  `id="liArticle"` I can't take the right <li>

Comment: `there is my template code for the Article` - don't use static value for id in a template that is likely to be used more than once

Comment: @Jerome - you'll need to use something else, like an id with a value after it (id1, id2, id3 etc)

Comment: Oh so the solution is to define the id dynamically in my JS ? :) @JaromandaX

Comment: if you can, can't see how you use the template, so, I can't say for sure

Comment: Use a class instead (`class="liArticle"`), select with `getElementsByClassName()` and choose the one you want with index (`document.getElementsByClassName("liArticle")[i].style.display`).

Comment: Thank you @JJJ I will remember to use class if there are more than 1 element !

Comment: actually since you're using jQuery it's `$(obj).closest(".liArticle").hide()`.

Comment: @JJJ Thank you for the JQuery solution it's always great to see the 2 methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @JJJ for the solution
 and if someone has the same problem you need to usea `class="idArticle"`   and to grab it with `document.getElementsByClassName("liArticle")[i].style.display="none";`

Or the second one is to do it with JQuery `$(obj).closest(".liArticle").hide();`